# sql: Cannot convert to Date

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have the following sql:

```
     select CONVERT(date,visitorannouncements.DateOfVisit), visitorannouncements.Agent,
            Firstname, visitors.Lastname 
       from Visitors

       LEFT JOIN visitorannouncements 
            ON Visitors.VisitorAnnouncementId=visitorannouncements.Id
      where ship = @shipname 
        AND convert(datetime, visitorannouncements.DateOfVisit,101) BETWEEN  @startDate AND @endDate
```

The visitorannouncements.DateOfVisit is nvarchar field.

I get the following error:

> TITLE: Microsoft SQL Server Report Builder
>
> ---
>
> An error occurred while
>   reading data from the query result set. The conversion of a nvarchar
>   data type to a datetime data type resulted in an out-of-range value.
>
> ---
>
> ADDITIONAL INFORMATION:
>
> The conversion of a nvarchar data type to a datetime data type resulted in an out-of-range value. (Microsoft SQL Server, Error: 242)

Comment: Start by deleting the duplicated row `from Visitors`

Comment: Is this the correct query? You have `from Visitors` twice there! Please format your query correctly, that helps a lot!

Comment: Paste error, not on the query

Comment: Just as an aside you'd be better off parsing the DateOfVisit at the source (WebApp/Rich Client) so when it gets to your database it's a true DateTime type. That or have a process that cleans up data before you send it to SSRS.

Answer (score 0):

Try finding out which `visitorannouncements.DateOfVisit` is not a valid date:

```
select *
from visitorannouncements
where isdate(DateOfVisit) = 0
```

Answer (score 0):

Specify the correct [style](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187928.aspx) to match the data string.

```
CONVERT ( data_type [ ( length ) ] , expression [ , style ] )
```